How to find files in a folder structure and group them into a new folder - Windows CMD
I´m looking for a way to search for files (pdf) in a folder structure that have a common identifier although in different parts of the file name (Eg. "10000 january.pdf" and "march 10000.pdf") and have those files moved to a separate folder that is named as the identifier (Eg. 10000). Thing is there about 10,000 separate files and over 1000 identifiers. Is there a way to feed a list of the identifiers to sort the files into this new structure?

Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].
